# Query linked Vertex in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to query a Vertex (B) that is linked to a vertex (A) that I'm querying. I tried below query, but it returns the linked vertex(B) not the vertex (A) that I've selected .

```
select expand(out(A)[title='xyz']) from A
```

This returns all Vertices from B. I need to how this fits in the where clause.

Comment: Hi, how is it your structure ? Like this: `A(class) ---unNamedEdge--> B(class)` ?

Comment: If your structure is A(class) ---unNamedEdge--> B(class) you can use select from A where out("unNamedEdge").title contains 'xyz'

Comment: @AlessandroRota: Your query did work as is, but doesn't work with an '='. Any way to make it exact?

Comment: @user3295878 out("unNamedEdge") return a list, so you must use "contains" and not "="

Comment: @AlessandroRota Fundamental question, wouldn't a contains filter be expensive as compared to an exact match? I don't know the exact workings of OrientDB and am just curious. I'd be glad if you could explain this out.

Comment: @user3295878 I wouldn't know. You can use also select from A where "xyz" IN out("unNamedEdge").title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created this structure to try your case:

[image]

I have these options to get the results you're looking for:

**Query 1**:

```
select from A where out(E)[title='xyz'].size() > 0
```

**Output**:

```
----+-----+------+-----+--------
#   |@RID |@CLASS|title|out_
----+-----+------+-----+--------
0   |#12:0|A     |abc  |[size=3]
----+-----+------+-----+--------
```

**Query 2**:

```
select from A where out(E).title contains 'xyz'
```

**Output**:

```
----+-----+------+-----+--------
#   |@RID |@CLASS|title|out_
----+-----+------+-----+--------
0   |#12:0|A     |abc  |[size=3]
----+-----+------+-----+--------
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for trying this out. But, I need to see the values from class A whereas in the above output, the class is shown as B, which is why I wanted to use where clause. As mentioned in my comment, the where clause worked but only for contains criteria. I need an exact match. Can you help me on that?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've just replaced my answer with the correct content.

Comment: The second query worked and the output is expected. Thankfully it also worked on the next linked Vertex. eg. select from A where out(E1).out(E2).title contains 'xyz'. How long can I keep on chaining like this till it starts affecting the database performance?

Comment: Hi, it's hard to say, it also depends on how many records your DB has got (and other variables). If this was your case, you can implement several queries to increase performance, such as subqueries and / or specific conditions at different levels.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from being more direct, wouldn't the following generally be more efficient than beginning at A?

```
select in(E) from (select from B where title='xyz') unwind in
```